# Instant search , facetFilter does not work with tilder.(~)

Tags: algolia, instantsearch, typesense

I'm trying to implement a typesense search with instantsearch, and trying to use facetFilters, and it works very well, the problem is that the name of some items that were sent to typesense are with "tilder" (~), because in Portuguese do Brazil, which is what I'm doing is very common. But whenever I need to filter an element with the "tilder" (~) such as "composição" it doesn't bring any result. How can I include the "tilder" in my searches?

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Could you open your browser's dev console, click on the network tab. Then in your UI click on the "composição" filter, and then look at the `multi_search` API call generated in the network tab, and share the network request payload with the actual search request sent to Typesense?

Answer (score 0):

Algolia performs a series of normalizations on queries that includes removing diacritics like "~":

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/optimize-search-results/handling-natural-languages-nlp/in-depth/normalization/

You may have to modify some of the normalization settings (like `keepDiacriticsOnCharacters`) to get the result you are looking for.